# Azure Devops PreDefined Variables in JMeter (Blazemeter)

Tags: azure-devops, jmeter, blazemeter

[image]

Currently I am integrating using Blazemeter plugin in azure devops for the JMeter script . I have one issue I am trying with different combination to pass the PreDefined variables in azure for JMeter . What I am trying is I am trying to pass the User Defined Variable of JMeter in Azure Pre-Defined Variable . But I am unable to do so . I have tried different combination , following pre-defined document .   The reason to do so is . Suppose tomorrow any non technical person just want to run the script by just change the environment at predefined level in azure instead of changing them in JMeter User Defined Variable or you can say by making any change in the script of .jmx . I have tried different combination of integration of predefined . One of the combination i have shared with screenshot . If anyone have any idea please let me know . One more thing in Release.EnvironmentUri I have checked the release because of that I am able to send those value at run time ..[image]

Let me elaborate more Here in this image. I have also shared the plugins I am using. [image]. [image]

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to set an [environment variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable) like below:

[image]

And in JMeter's [User Defined Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#User_Defined_Variables) read the variable value using [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy)

```
${__groovy(System.getenv('Release.EnvironmentUri'),)}
```

[image]

More information: [Testing via Azure DevOps Pipeline](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360004191957-Testing-via-Azure-DevOps-Pipeline)